# How to TextWrap a TextBlock within a width Auto Column?

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, textblock

Consider something as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="WrapTextBlock" Grid.Column="0" Text="123 456 789 0123 4456 123  123  123  123 1 23  123 " TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="NotWrapTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Text="GGG" />
</Grid>
```

This XAML will allow `WrapTextBlock` text to be wrap, doing this, `WrapTextBlock` will take all the space and push `NotWrapTextBlock` to the right.

But what I want to do is to have `WrapTextBlock` take as less space as possible, pushing `NotWrapTextBlock` right after `WrapTextBlock` and fill the right side with empty space.

Which means the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="WrapTextBlock" Grid.Column="0" Text="123 456 789 0123 4456 123  123  123  123 1 23  123 " TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="NotWrapTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Text="GGG" />
</Grid>
```

But the thing here is, now the text in `WrapTextBlock` wouldn't wrap anymore.

I mean something like follows:

When text is too long it requires to warp:

[image]

When text is short enough that doesn't requires to warp:

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason is by defining your `ColumnDefinition` as Auto or * you have nothing to limit the size available for your `TextBlock` to consume. So it would be expected behavior for the Text to not Wrap. So you'll have to define a `Width` or `MaxWidth` on either the `ColumnDefinition` or the `TextBlock` directly. So for instance;

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MaxWidth="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="WrapTextBlock" Text="123 456 789 0123 4456 123  123  123  123 1 23  123 " TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="NotWrapTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Text="GGG" />
    </Grid>
```

Will give you your wrap, if you want to say instead only allow it to take for example say, 7% of the space the grid has to use, change the `Width` to something like;

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.07*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="0.93*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

So the first column will take up 7% of the space available, and the right column will consume the rest. Hope this helps.

Edit Addition:

What you're showing pretty much aligns with your first snippet wherein the first column should push, the second one should only allow enough space for its content to show;

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="WrapTextBlock" Grid.Column="0" Text="123 456 789 0123 4456 123  123  123  123 1 23  123 " TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="NotWrapTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Text="GGG" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This I understand, but this is restricting WrapTextBlock's column to only take up to contains width.  What I don't want to see is there is empty space between WrapTextBlock and NotWrapTextBlock.  And NotWrapTextBlock is not getting pushed to the rightmost.

Comment: Sounds like a consideration for the `Grid` itself, if it has more space than necessary it's going to take it. Maybe a quick image of what you want, as opposed to what you get would help define it?

Comment: Edited at the bottom, your first snippet should do what you're thinking provided the Grid itself has a limited amount of space to invoke the TextWrapping

Comment: Ohhh, I figured out.  I should wrap the Grid with another Grid.  And just set this Grid's HoriontalAlignment="Left".  It worked, thanks. (Haven't touch UI for too long.......)

Comment: Good deal, glad you found your remedy. Cheers!

Comment: I don't think your first answer works - MaxWidth doesn't seem to wrap text. Have you tried this?

Comment: @NathanPhillips This is a pretty old answer, but MaxWidth should pretty much always invoke wrapping (provided you have TextWrapping=Wrap set of course). I'd have to assume it's something specific to your scenario. If you'd like maybe share details in another question and we can take a look at the details.

Comment: @ChrisW. MaxWidth does not wrap the text.

Comment: @Wobbles howdy, as in the comment just previous of yours I'll have to assume it's something specific to your scenario. Having a set width should always invoke wrapping if you've declared TextWrapping="Wrap" as such.

Comment: @ChrisW. We arent using a set width, as the comment Nathan made says, we are looking to use `MaxWidth`. Setting the `Width` does in fact work, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Wobbles MaxWidth should also still invoke wrapping. I'd have to see the instance in which it's used to identify your culprit.